# Destructor of class with pointer array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, destructor, delete-operator

If I have a class with an array of pointers to another class *Vehicle* :

```
class List {
    public:
        //stuff goes here
    private:
        Vehicle ** vehicles;
}
```

If I now write the destructor of the class `List`, do I manually iterate over the array (I know how many items are in the array) and `delete` every pointer to a vehicle, or will C++ automatically call the destructors of all the Vehicles in the array?

(Like it does if there's a private string/... in the class or if it would be a STL container of Vehicle pointers)

EDIT:
I forgot about `delete [] vehicles`, but if I would do that, would it also delete the memory used by all the vehicles in the array, or would it just delete the memory used by the pointers?

Comment: Use `vector` and `boost::scoped_ptr`. If you use C++0x, use `vector` and `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @Alexandre this is a small question of a previous exam of a course i'm taking, i *would* use a vector if it would be allowed on that exam :)

Comment: @Alexandre: haha, fortunately this is the only time they use this and we use vectors etc. any other time. I believe his intentions were to make something clear about polymorphism and arrays or something...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to delete all the entries in the array AND delete the array.
There are methods in C++ (STL) to avoid this: use a vector, so you don't have to delete the array.  Use scoped_ptr/shared_ptr per Vehicle, so you don't have to delete the vehicles.

Comment: One clarification, STL is only a subset of C++ Standard Library. shared_ptr is not part of STL, but C++ Standard Library (as defined in upcoming C++0x as well as included in Boost collection). scoped_ptr is not part of any version of C++ Standard Library, only Boost.

Answer (score 3):

If the List owns Vehicle objects (creates them in the constructor) you need to delete every single one and then delete the array of pointers itself.

Comment: +1: Regardless of the available better options like STL it's important when learning a language to grasp this concept.  A rule to make special note of is if you use new[] to allocate you must use delete[] to deallocate or you will run into corruption issues.

Answer (score 2):

> If i have a class with an array of pointers to another class Vehicle :
>   `Vehicle ** vehicles;`

`vehicles` is not an array of pointers rather its a pointer to pointer to a `Vehicle` type.
An array of pointers would be defined something like `Vehicle* vehicles[N]`.

> do i manually iterate over the array (i know how many items are in the array) and delete every pointer to a vehicle

Yes! You dont want your code to leak memory do you?

I would recommend using `Boost::scoped_ptr` from the Boost library. Moreover if you compiler supports C++0x you can also use `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: This is how my professor explained it in an exercise, *and* honestly, i also thought it was `Vehicle * vehicles[n]` :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually iterate over vehicles and `delete` each and every of them.