# Destructor for pointer to fixed size array

Tags: c++, debugging, pointers, destructor

Suppose I have a C++ class with two private variables. A fixed size array, `data`, and a pointer to that array, `pnt`.

```
class MyClass
{
   private:
      double *pnt;
      double data[2];
   public:
      myClass();
      virtual ~MyClass();
      double* getPnt() const;
      void setPnt(double* input);
};

MyClass::MyClass()
{

   double * input;
   data[0] = 1;
   data[1] = 2;

   input= data;
   setPnt(input);
}

MyClass::~MyClass()
{
 delete this->pnt; // This throws a runtime error
}


void MyClass::setPnt(double * input)
{
   pnt = input;
}

double * MyClass::getPnt() const;
{
   return pnt;
}

int main()
{
   MyClass spam; // Construct object
   delete spam; // Error C2440: 'delete' cannot convert from 'MyClass' to 'void*'
}
```

There are two problems with this code. First if I try to call delete on the object, I get:

> Error C2440: 'delete' cannot convert from 'MyClass' to 'void*'

Secondly, if I comment out the delete statement, I get a realtime error stating a debug assertion failed! and this:

```
Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)
```

My question is then: **For a class with a pointer to a private fixed size array, how do I properly free memory, write/call the destructor?**

P.S I can't use `vector` or nice containers like that (hence this question).

Comment: This is a similar question but we are asking different things because I have a private static array:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748669/destructor-of-class-with-pointer-array-c

Comment: I see no static array. I see a fixed-size array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see no static array. I see a fixed-size array. Also memory for `data` is allocated as part of the object.

You must not explicitely delete a member of the class: the delete operator will take care of that **IFF** the instance was dynamically allocated.

```
 {
      MyClass x; // auto variable
 } // x destructor run, no delete operator
```

vs.

```
 {
      MyClass* x = new MyClass(); // heap allocation variable
      delete x; // x destructor run, ::delete de-allocates from heap
 }
```

Comment: Why do I not want to explicitly delete the pointer. Don't I want to free the memory allocated to it?

Comment: I have expanded the answer. In short; you only want to delete what you allocate. You do _not_ allocate `data[2]`: it is part of (a member of) your class.

Comment: The answers the `delete` part of the question, what about the pointer,`pnt`? Do I not need `delete` because `new` wasn't used?

Comment: @Elpezmuerto: Exactly. You do not want to `delete` the pointer because you did not allocate it with `new`. The target of a `delete` statement *must* be something you allocated with `new`. The only exception: the pointer is null.

Comment: Exactly. And, yes, that was in the answer. `pnt` merely points to `data`, so when I say you shouldn't be deallocating `data`, that means you should be deleting _through_ any other pointer to `data` either.

Answer (score 2):

`data` is a subobject, it will be deallocated when the `MyClass` instance goes away.  The compiler will insert any necessary code into the `MyClass` destructor to call destructors for all subobjects before the memory is freed.